# Метод сравнения двух переменных

Tags: php

Подобная конструкция будет верна?

```
protected function compareStatus($first, $second) {
    if($first == $second) return 1;
}
```

Метод сравнивает две переменные и возвращает true, если они совпадают.

Comment: Почему бы и не возвращать return TRUE ?

Comment: а если не равны, то что будет?

Comment: Вообще сама конструкция будет себя вести, как описано, но не проще ли напрямую делать $a == $b? если уж так надо получить единицу, делайте type casting: $one = (int)($a == $b);

Answer (score 0):

на первый взгляд вижу два способа сравнения

```
protected function compareStatus($first, $second) {
    return ($first == $second) ? true : false;
}

protected function compareStatus($first, $second) {
    return (strcasecmp($first, $second)) ? false : true;
}
```

читаем о [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcasecmp.php)

Comment: а разве нельзя вместо

    return ($first == $second) ? true : false;

написать просто

    return $first == $second;

Comment: @KoVadim, можно)